# alternative shows the radio content by jquery?

Tags: jquery

the html structure:

```
<div id="test">
   <form>
   <input type="radio" name="content"  class="s_code" checked="checked" /><span>code</span>
    <input type="radio" name="content"  class="s_book" /><span>book</span>
    </form>
   </div>
 <div class="contenta">
 <a href="one/letter_A_1.html">A</a>

<a href="two/letter_B_1.html">B</a>

<a href="three/letter_C_1.html">C</a>

<a href="four/letter_D_1.html">D</a>
</div>
 <div class="contentb">
 <a href="1/letter_A_1.html">A</a>

<a href="2/letter_B_1.html">B</a>

<a href="3/letter_C_1.html">C</a>

<a href="4/letter_D_1.html">D</a>
</div></div>
```

now, is there a way to get when i checked the book radio, the `contentb` showing. the `contenta` is hidden. the default shows is `contenta`.

Comment: Like Shankar mentioned below, your radio buttons need a 'name' attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use toggle, this way you can add more sections if you need to.  If you have over 5 sections, I would NOT use this method.

```
$('.s_code, .s_book').change(function() {
    $('.contenta').toggle($(this).hasClass('s_code'));
    $('.contentb').toggle($(this).hasClass('s_book'));
});
```

Comment: It works, I tested it in jsfiddle.  Make sure you encapsulate that logic in the document.ready() function. http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/9YnYL/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function(){

  $(".contentb").hide();

  $(".s_book").change(function(){
     if(this.checked){
       $(".contentb").show();
       $(".contenta").hide();
     }
  });

});
```

The radio buttons should always be grouped by name, but in your case I dont know why you haven't give them the name. If you give the name(groupname) to these radio buttons you can check either of those. By giving name(e.g content) to radio buttons the code will be like this

**Change in Markup**

```
<form>
   <input type="radio" name="content" value="contenta" class="s_code" checked="checked" /><span>code</span>
    <input type="radio" name="content" value="contentb" class="s_book" /><span>book</span>
    </form>
```

**JS**

$(function(){

```
  $(".contentb").hide();

  $("input[name=content]").change(function(){
     $(".contenta, .contentb").hide();
     $("."+this.value).show();
  });

});
```

Comment: the code can't work, when i click to the second radio, all the content are hidden.